# How can i add numbers to an array using scan f

Tags: c

I want to add numbers to an array using scanf
What did i do wrong? it says expected an expression on the first bracket { in front of i inside the scanf...

```
void addScores(int a[],int *counter){
    int i=0;
    printf("please enter your score..");
    scanf_s("%i", a[*c] = {i});
}//end add scores
```

Comment: `a[*c] = {i}` is no expression, since `{i}` is no expression … also you mix up `counter` and `c`. I guess you think of dynamic arrays. C does not have such a thing natively. Maybe you should have a look into C++?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?  The expression `a[*c] = {i}` is not valid C syntax, as far as I know.  (What language(s) did you learn before C?)

Comment: @John looks like Matlab/Octave. With `a(end+1) = {value};` you would append a new cell to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suggests that you expect that your array will be dynamically resized; but that's not what happens in C. You have to create an array of the right size upfront. Assuming that you allocated enough memory in your array for all the scores you might want to collect, the following would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addScores(int *a, int *count) {
  return scanf("%d", &a[(*count)++]);
}

int main(void) {
  int scores[100];
  int sCount = 0;
  int sumScore = 0;
  printf("enter scores followed by <return>. To finish, type Q\n");
  while(addScores(scores, &sCount)>0 && sCount < 100);
  printf("total number of scores entered: %d\n", --sCount);
  while(sCount >= 0) sumScore += scores[sCount--];
  printf("The total score is %d\n", sumScore);
}
```

A few things to note:

1. The function `addScores` doesn't keep track of the total count: that variable is kept in the main program
2. A simple mechanism for end-of-input: if a letter is entered, `scanf` will not find a number and return a value of 0
3. Simple prompts to tell the user what to do are always an essential part of any program - even a simple five-liner.
4. There are more compact ways of writing certain expressions in the above - but in my experience, clarity ALWAYS trumps cleverness - and the compiler will typically optimize out any apparent redundancy. Thus - don't be afraid of extra parentheses to make sure you will get what you intended.
5. If you *do* need to dynamically increase the size of your array, look at `realloc`. It can be used in conjunction with `malloc` to create arrays of variable size. But it won't work if your initial array is declared as in the above code snippet.
6. Testing for a return value (of `addScores`, and thus effectively of `scanf`) `>0` rather than `!=0` catches the case where someone types ctrl-D ("EOF") to terminate input. Thanks @chux for the suggestion!

Comment: Maybe `while(addScores(scores, &sCount) > 0 ...` to cope with EOF?

Comment: @chux - you make a valid point. I did not think of the case where someone typed a ctrl-D rather than another letter. That scenario would indeed break my code example; and your suggestion does fix it. Updating my answer now...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
void addScores(int *a, int count){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       printf("please enter your score..");
       scanf("%d", a+i);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int main() {
    int scores[6];
    addScores(scores, 6);
}
```

Comment: Curious as to why the suggested answers use "%d" when OP used "%i"?  Either is OK here though slightly different in the input they accept.

Answer (score 2):

```
a+i is not friendly to newcomer.
```

I suggest

```
scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

Comment: `a+i` vs `&a[i]`? I understand your point, but I'll keep `a+i`.

Comment: Yes, but I think that &a[i] is easier to understand for newcomer. It's just a habit problem to old fish.